# In DSA, can we tell if signatures are for the same key pair?

Tags: dsa

We are given some distinct [DSA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A53%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C700%2C0%5D) signatures $(r_i,s_i)$ and the distinct hashes $H_i$ of the corresponding messages. The signatures and messages are non-maliciously made per the same known group parameters $(p,q,g)$ (say the [2048-bit MODP group with 256-bit prime order subgroup of RFC 5114](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5114.html#section-2.3)), using either one of two distinct non-maliciously drawn public/private key pairs. We do not know these public keys, much less these private keys.

Can we tell whether two signatures pertain to the same public key?

Inspired by [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/107260/555).